# Subcodes with trivial automorphism group

Tags: coding-theory

Let $C$ be a linear code having the trivial automorphism group. How can we find all subcodes of $C$ having the trivial automorphism group? Does such a subcode always exist? Can we answer if the code is constant-weight?